# (black) why the pawn H6 is not good move in this position?

Tags: sicilian-defense, pawns, knights, smith-morra-gambit

[image]

(My turn[black])

I want to attack the g5 knight, so I up the pawn at H6, but the chess engine evaluate 3.4 to 1.3 my winning points. Instead engine recommended pawn D6, pawn D5, king H8 is better move.
why the pawn H6 is not good move, but above moves are better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To avoid a weak square on d5.**

Black has a winning position with an healthy extra central pawn.

However, after 1...h6? 2.Ne4 the only defender of d5, the Nf6, gets exchanged. It means that White can get control of d5 for quite a long time (eventually Black will probably snap it back, but it will take a long fight), e.g. 2...Nxe4 3.Qxe4 d6 4.Bc4. Black is still much better, but with the backward Pd6 they have a complicated technical task ahead of them.

On the other hand, after 1...d5! the central pawn pair is immediately set in motion and dominates White pieces. Without access to e4,d4,c4,d5,e5,f4, White won't be able to mount any real counterplay, so Black can confidently continue with ...h6 (no Ne4 now) ...Be6, ...Qc7 or ...Qd7, ...Rad8, and force White to always be careful of pawn forks.

Comment: Thanks to you, I think I can raise my chess rating :)